# "undefined" returned when accessing some listed properties of File object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, fileapi

I can't seem to access the width or height keys of my object.

I'm using dropzone.js which has an event for addedFile which returns the file and the first param.

so:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {url: '/'});

myDropzone.on('addedFile', function(file) {
    console.log(file);
});
```

The callback works just fine, in my console I see:
[image]

As you can see, there's clearly the height & width keys available.

```
myDropzone.on('addedFile', function(file) {
    console.log(file.name); // returns the whole strong
    console.log(file.width); // returns undefined
    console.log(file['width']);  // returns undefined
});
```

Heres a screenshot:

[image]

My question is, why is name available, but not width or height? Is it because they're readonly or something? If that's the case, is it even possible to access it?

Comment: Ah, that did it, 100miliseconds was enough to access it :) is it possible though that sometimes it wont be defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `File.width` property is a DropzoneJS extension and is not a part of the core [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File); it is *added later*.

> Dropzone adds data to the file object you can use *when* events fire. You can access `file.width` and `file.height` if it's an image..

*If applicable* the image size information is made available *by the time* the `"thumbnail"` event occurs. It is *not* guaranteed to be set before this event.

The documentation isn't very clear on this only alluding to "when the thumbnail has been generated", but such is the [behavior of the source](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.coffee) (see the createThumbnail/resize functions) - the image size is collected *when* the thumbnail is generated.

---

The initial behavior is seen because `console.log` (in browsers, eg. Chrome, that treat it similar to `console.dir`) displays the "live" object. This in turn has given enough time for the *asynchronous* thumbnail generation, and associated image dimension gathering, to complete before the browser displays the object's now-assgined properties in the console. (This also explains why using a timeout to read the property value works - even though such is *not* a reliable approach.)

On the other hand, directly accessing the `file.width` forces immediate evaluation of the still-not-set property, which results in `undefined` in the `"addedFile"` callback.

Comment: do you think creating a recurrsive callback with a limit would be a better solution to get this data?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins No. The only correct way to get the information is to *wait* for the `thumbnail` event to be fired. If successful, this will be invoked at some point after the `addedFile` event.

Answer (score 7):

So just to make things clear. As user2864740 said, you need to wait for the "thumbnail" event. This would result in this code:

```
myDropzone.on('addedFile', function(file) {
  myDropzone.on("thumbnail", function(file){            
     console.log(file);   
     console.log(file.width); // returns width
     console.log(file['width']);  // returns width
  });
});
```

You could even use it in accept method like this:

```
myDropzone.on('accept', function(file, done){
   myDropzone.on("thumbnail", function(file){
     if(file.width != 728 && file.height != 90){
       done("Resolution is not correct (Super Banner (728x90))");
     } else {
       done();
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Note that when supporting multiple uploads, it seems like it will fire for every file/thumbnail combination. Adding a uuid check resolves that: `if(file.upload.uuid == thumbnail.upload.uuid) { /* do stuff here */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Add a dirty timeout will not work everytime, you will get some indefined when you will send huge files or multiples files.

I got the same headache and personnaly gave up to check width and height before uploading and check in the server side. In fact you can display dropzone errors  by returning an header error:

```
$size = getimagesize(current($_FILES['value']['tmp_name']));

if($size[0] == 840 && $size[1] == 570){
    //perfect
}
else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable");
    echo 'Your image must be 840x570px';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From you to write the code to see nothing wrong, maybe the type of file isn't object but string, you can try the method JSON.parse(file) and then get the key of width.

Comment: its definitely an object

Answer (score -1):

I used timeout 50ms in complete function and undefined is gone.