# Width and height "undefined" on sending event

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-forms, dropzone.js

I'm trying to append the files' width and height to my formData during the sending event, but it always appears as "undefined":

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        Dropzone.options.dropZone = {
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 64, // MB
            dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> \
                 <span class="main-text"><b>Drop Files</b> to upload</span> <br /> \
                 <span class="sub-text">(or click, max file size: 64 MB)</span> \
                ',
            dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
            init: function () {
                this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    // Will send the filesize along with the file as POST data.
                    console.log(file.width); //display "undefined"
                    formData.append("width", file.width);
                    formData.append("height", file.height);
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

What can I do to access the file's dimensions and send it to my controller (Symfony)?

Comment: Use the `thumbnail` event – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927381/undefined-returned-when-accessing-some-listed-properties-of-file-object?rq=1 – but only for display to the user. The server can determine the width and height on its own and shouldn’t trust the client to provide accurate information.

Comment: @minitech You're right. I just went with the regular `getimagesize($uploadedFile)` in PHP, just as mentioned in the post you referred. Thanks for the help :)